# Return true if all rows in column are true

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, calculated-columns

I've a new hobby called "turn bad tasting liqueurs into something good" a.k.a. "mix cocktails".

Since I'm a nerd I don't want to look up recipes in a book, read the ingredients list and notice that I've some stuff missing. Instead I want to have a database with all my collected recipes, and ingredients and let the computer tell me which recipes I can 'build' with the ingredients I currently have at home. For this purpose I've this two tables:

Table 1: holds information about a many-to-many relationship

```
recipe | ingredient
1      | 1          
1      | 2          
1      | 3          
2      | 1         
2      | 4
```

Table 2: information wether this ingredient is available or not

```
ingredient | available
1          | true
2          | true
3          | true
4          | false
```

All other tables aren't interesting for my problem.

These two tables can easily `INNER JOIN`-ed with `ingredient = ingredients.id` to one big table that looks like:

```
recipe | ingredient | available
1      | 1          | true
1      | 2          | true
1      | 3          | true
2      | 1          | true
2      | 4          | false
```

If you take a look at this, you'll notice that I can mix the recipe 1, but not recipe two since one ingredient is missing.

What I want to do now is to find a way so that the result looks like:

```
recipe | all_available
1      | true
2      | false
```

I already found a way to check if all ingredients for a certain recipe are available or not:

```
SELECT RtI.recipe, BIT_AND(ingredients.available) AS all_available
FROM RtI
INNER JOIN ingredients ON (ingredients.id = RtI.ingredient)
WHERE RtI.recipe = 1
```

Which results:

```
recipe | all_available
1      | true
```

But you have to search of a specific ID, what I want is not "show me if all ingredients are available for this recipe" but "show me all recipes for which all ingredients are available".

Is there a way to achieve this just by using MySQL queries?

Comment: Look for "relational division" queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the great help!

Based on your hints I can now answer my own question and share my final solution with you:

```
SELECT RtI.recipe, recipes.title, ( SUM(ingredients.available) / COUNT(ingredients.available) ) AS available
FROM RtI
LEFT JOIN ingredients ON (ingredients.id = RtI.ingredient)
LEFT JOIN recipes ON (recipes.id = RtI.recipe)
GROUP BY RtI.recipe
ORDER BY ( SUM(ingredients.available) / COUNT(ingredients.available) ) DESC, recipes.title
```

This gives me a table like:

```
recipe | title       | available
1      | Pina Colada | 1.00
2      | Caipirinha  | 0.50
```

It's a bit more to write with all the brackets and functions, but I think this is what "views" are for.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `WHERE` condition and instead use `GROUP BY RtI.recipe`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT recipe, MIN(COALESCE(ingredients.available,0)) all_available
FROM rti LEFT JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id=rti.ingredient
GROUP BY recipe
```

`all_available` will be `0` for recipes with missing ingredients and `1` for 'complete' recipes.

**Edit**
Just in case, the ingredient is not even listed in the ingredients table I added a `COALESCE`. Probably not necessary, since the `RtI` table is probably machine generated and will only conatin valid `id`s ...

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY:
SELECT r.recipe AS recipe, BIT_AND( i.available ) AS all_available
FROM RtI AS r
INNER JOIN ingredients AS i
ON ( r.ingredient = i.ingredient )
GROUP BY r.recipe